# JQGrid editOptions Values not working

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

Ok, so we've got the latest JQGrid grid working beautifully, but the editoption value param doesn't seem to do the required replaces in the grid values. This did work in a previous version. The EditForm works perfectly.

```
...{ 
   name: 'Field1', 
   index: 'Field1' , 
   editable: true, 
   edittype:'select',
   editoptions:{
      dataUrl: 'lookup.dasl?EntityAttributeID=1345',
      value: {1:'ABC',2:'CDE',3:'EFG'}
   },
}...
```

Comment: We tried combinations of dataUrl and value, but still nothing...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I find non-logical that you use both `dataUrl` and `value` parameters of `editoptions`. I verified in both 3.7.1 and 3.6.5 versions of jqGrid in grid.common.js in the `createEl` function there are such code fragment:

```
switch (eltype)
{
    // ...
    case "select" :
        // ...
        if(typeof(options.dataUrl) != "undefined") {
            // ...
        } else if(options.value) {
            // ...
        }
        break;
```

So if you define `dataUrl` then `value` parameters of `editoptions` will be ignored.

**UPDATED**: The usage of `formatter:'select'` is not important for the question which you asked. If you send back in the response on `dataUrl` the values 1, 2 or 3 (the keys) instead of the values 'ABC', 'CDE' and 'EFG' then you should use `formatter:'select'`. If all cases the `value` parameter of `editoptions` will be ignored if you use also `dataUrl`.

Comment: Awesome, Wasn't sure if the two were mutually exclusive.. Prefer using value param...  Tx

Comment: I agree. If you knows statically the values, then the usage of `value` is more quickly as the usage of dynamic construction `dataUrl`.

Answer (score 2):

WTF!!! Had to dig deep into the documentation for this one.

Just needed to add "formatter: 'select'"

AAAAAAAAAAAAAHHH!

Comment: omgawd, that's right. Here it wasn't working in non-edit mode, but once I put the formatter:'select' it started to work, phew.